# Google's cache is not using my custom font

Tags: css, fonts, css3, google-cache

When I check my site’s cache view on Google Search, I see Google does not use my custom font, it always replaces mine with Arial. Because of font widths, my whole design is changing.

I have these lines on my CSS file, and eveything is ok on desktop and mobile view:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'helveticaneuelt_std_lt_cnRg';
src: url('http://www.example.com/css/helveticaneueltstd.eot');
src: url('http://www.example.com/css/helveticaneueltstd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('http://www.example.com/css/helveticaneueltstd.svg') format('svg'),
     url('http://www.example.com/css/helveticaneueltstd.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://www.example.com/css/helveticaneueltstd.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Do you have any idea why Google’s cache system does not use my custom font?

Original site: [goo.gl/0CCIc8](http://www.goo.gl/0CCIc8)
Cache view: [goo.gl/7NR4E1](http://www.goo.gl/7NR4E1)

UPDATE: I found solution by using fonts with base64 mod.

Comment: It'd be useful to let us know when you added the custom fonts... i.e how many days, weeks or months ago...

Comment: about 2 years ago :/

Comment: Give us the url of your site. Then maybe checking the cache I might be able to figure something out. Also it's poor design if your site breaks because of fonts width. Google Cache is the least of your worries in that case.

Comment: The font-types don't really play a role for indexing, so that's not really something I'd lose any sleep over.

Comment: "UPDATE: I found solution by using fonts with base64 mod." -- You could/should add and describe this solution in an answer.

Comment: Agree with unor. How do you use fonts with base64 mod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal for sites to look a little bit different in cache view.  The cache usually tries to load resources from your server.   This is problematic when:

- Users are using the cache because your site is down or slow
- Resources are not permitted by the browser to be loaded cross domain

The latter may be the problem with fonts.   It sounds like you found a workaround by encoding the fonts using base64 in your CSS file.

Most webmasters don't worry much about how their site looks in the Google cache.   Displaying badly in cache doesn't effect rankings.  Only a small percentage of users actually view your site like that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but it's the first one in the Google search results. I've been searching for a solution and after some weeks of unsuccessfull testing, I could find the solution. Add this code in your `.htaccess`:

```
# Allow access from all domains for web fonts
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The fact is, that the problem is not in the Google's side, indexing wrong. The problem is in the server side, about the following error:

`Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

After editing the `.htaccess` file and clearing the browser's cache, the fonts are displayed again in the Google's cached pages, instantly!